# Calculating and Plotting Rolling Proportions of Customer Interactions in a Time Series DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, plot, timestamp, rolling-computation

I have a pandas DataFrame representing a time series with two columns: 'interaction_type' and 'timestamps'. The 'interaction_type' column contains categorical values ('Chat', 'Call', 'Email', etc.), and the 'timestamps' column contains corresponding timestamps.
Example Data:

```
 interaction_type           timestamps
1                Chat  2017-05-01 00:00:01
2                Chat  2017-05-01 00:00:04
3                Chat  2017-05-01 00:00:15
4                Chat  2017-05-01 00:00:15
5                Chat  2017-05-01 00:00:21
6                Call  2017-05-01 00:00:24
7                Chat  2017-05-01 00:00:31
8               Email  2017-05-01 00:00:32
```

I want to calculate the rolling proportions of each customer interaction type ('Chat', 'Call', 'Email', etc.) within a rolling time window ('5s', '10s' etc.) i.e. number of rows of each interaction type by the total number of rows in each time window. Then I want to plot these against the time window timestamps on the same plot.

I tried setting the timestamps as the DataFrame index and using groupby, resample and rolling methods but can't quite get it to work. I'm working with a huge dataset and would like to stick to vectorized operations and no big loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You could use a combination of `pd.date_range`, `pd.DataFrame.merge`, `pd.DataFrame.value_counts` and `pd.get_dummies(df).rolling` to apply functions across windows of previously per-second grouped-by counted frequencies of the events listed by timestamp:

E.g.,

#### A) Create a skeleton time series-indexed dataframe with regular intervals

In this example, I chose the whole 24 hours of one day (May 1, 2017), randomly sampled 100,000 seconds from all 86,400 possible, and randomly assigned these second-level-precision timestamps to a draw from `["chat", "email", "call"]`. So, some seconds may have multiple values (even of the same interaction type), while some seconds may randomly have no values. Hence the need to create a regularly-indexed "skeleton" dataframe to merge with the dataset.

```py
import datetime
import random

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


dates = [
    datetime.datetime(
        2017,
        5,
        1,
        random.randint(0, 23),
        random.randint(0, 59),
        random.randint(0, 59),
    )
    for _ in range(100000)
]


ss = pd.date_range("05/01/2017", periods=86400, freq="s")
skeleton = pd.DataFrame(index=ss)

interactions = ["chat", "email", "call"]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "interaction_type": list(random.choices(interactions, k=len(dates))),
        "timestamp": dates,
    }
)

df = df.merge(skeleton, left_on="timestamp", right_index=True, how="outer")
df.set_index("timestamp", inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df
```

[image: df orig data]

#### B) Count the occurrences of each interaction type for every second within the timeseries index range

Here I used `pd.value_counts` instead of a groupby, and fill NaN's with zeros. Now we have the counts of each interaction type per second, and just need to calculate the rolling window sums next.

```py
df_agg = (
    df.value_counts(["timestamp", "interaction_type"], dropna=False)
    .sort_index()
    .unstack()
    .drop([np.nan], axis=1)
    .fillna(0)
)
df_agg
```

[image: agg df]

#### C) Calculate functions on rolling window sections of the frequency data of interaction types per second

I just realized in your question you're asking for percentages, so that will require a tiny bit of extra code. But hopefully this example illustrates clearly enough how you could alter the code below to perform whatever function you wished on the rolling windows of dataframe slices.

```py
df_window_sum = pd.get_dummies(df_agg).rolling('10s').sum()
df_window_sum
```

[image: rolling windows df 10 seconds]

### Visualization example of 10-second rolling window-summed counts by interaction type

```py
import plotly.express as px

df_window_sum.reset_index(inplace=True)
fig = px.line(df_window_sum, x="timestamp", y=interactions)
fig.show()
```

[image: visualization in plotly]